# how to assign db column value to variable and call it to tokenize in python

Tags: python, sqlite

I want assign the data which is retrieve from database (sqlit3) particular column  for a variable and call that variable for **word tokenize**.
please help with this

I know tokenize part but I want to know how to assign the db value to a variable in python.

Comment: Can I have a little more information? Like your db schema, what you need to do specifically. Are you trying to retrieve a specific record? Or that column for every record?

Comment: I want retrieve every record in a particular column                                                              
    "c.execute('SELECT answer FROM Can_Answer')
      row = c.fetchone()"                                                                                and how to assign that retrieved value to the variable?

Comment: Extract it from the row: `v = row[0]`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import sqlite3
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize

conn = sqlite3.connect('ACE.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('SELECT can_answer FROM 
Can_Answer')

// rows will have all the records from the can_answer field
rows = c.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    print(word_tokenize(row))
```

Comment: yes that's ok..and it works but what i want is, after retrieved the data, assign that data to another variable and use it for tokenize. I'm stuck with assign value to the variable part...please help me

Comment: Since `rows` contains a list of values from the `answer` field of your `Can_Answer` table, you can just pass the `rows` variable to your `tokenize` function and extract the required value using indexing like `rows[0]` or iterate over `rows` to get all the values like I did above and perform the operation.

Comment: when passing as 'row' it shows "Type Error" as, expected string or buffer". what it means and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you post the entire code snippet of both the querying part as well as the tokenize part? That way it'll easy to find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is worked but when using c.fetchall it didn't work.shows error saying TypeError: expected string or buffer

import sqlite3
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize

conn = sqlite3.connect('ACE.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('SELECT can_answer FROM Can_Answer')

rows = c.fetchone()

for row in rows:
    print(row)

print(word_tokenize(row))

Comment: Inside your word_tokenize function you've to loop the `row` variable to get the values. Can you post the `word_tokenize` function code snippet as well so that I can come up with an example for the same? And for posting code snippets you can use the comments section instead of answer section.

Comment: Edited my answer. Check now. Sorry I didn't see the `from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize` statement above and I thought it's your custom function.